# #Delete error on cells when excecute Delete Queries on Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Hei:
I have created a button where I run a group of Delete Queries on MS Access 2016 , to delete records from forms and subforms, to clean a main Form.
They have the following kind of SQL statement, to delete the records from the tables that feed my forms:

```
DELETE tblConfig.TenderID, *
FROM tblConfig
WHERE (((tblConfig.TenderID)=[Forms]![frmGI]![TenderID]));
```

When I run the queries, actually delete all the records from my tables but I get a #Deleted in all the deleted cells.Is there a way to make this dissappear?
I have googled the error, but have had no success on finding an answer.
Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on a specific record within the form (`[frmGI].[tenderID]`), which you then delete, so you will see the `#deleted`. If you delete a record, you will have to move to a new record or a different record.

If you are deleting subform records then you will need to `requery` your subform.

> EDIT:

To requery your subform use the following code syntax and insert after the queries have been taken place. The `#deleted` on a subform is due to a `refresh` taking place on the subform. Refresh and requery are not the same.

```
Forms!tblconfig.Form![subformName].Requery
```

Comment: I am deleteing actually subform records, then   I should add the  event  subforms. requery after my "run queries" event?

Comment: It worked poerfectly, but it wasnt needed to write the whole location, since the subform is in datasheet view, was just needed to add an empty  Requery ( no control name needed). Very usefull, thanks for the answer :)